# CSS3 Transformations using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I wanna handle the css3 transformations using keyframes with javascript.
This is a Question I've never got an answer that is favorable anywhere.
If the example is

```
@-webkit-keyframes move{
    from{
        -webkit-transform:translate(0px,0px);
    }
    to{
        -webkit-transform:translate(0px,-100px);
    }
}
```

How can I give those values of translate dynamically using javascript.

Comment: As far as I know, if you stick to CSS3 animation, you'll have to insert generated rule for keyframes as a <style> in your html. Ugly.

Comment: The same exact question has already been asked here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328933/set-the-webkit-keyframes-from-to-parameter-with-javascript

Comment: I am having some objects like smoke. And I wanna assign random() numbers to translate them randomly all over the page. And also need to scale and rotate the objects randomly. That's the reason I wanna handle the transformation with javascript.

Comment: @Denis The question you mentioned handles keyframes but not css3 transformations. Please consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scenario is slightly complicated with you not being able to explicitly assign an undeclared animation *even in css*; i.e. in your sample you're declaring a "move" animation.

That being said, you're able to generate stylesheets at runtime - the following CSS rules would be fairly trivial to generate:

```
@-webkit-keyframes moveA{/*keyframes*/}
#smokeA {-webkit-animation: moveA 5s infinite; }
@-webkit-keyframes moveB{/*keyframes*/}
#smokeB {-webkit-animation: moveB 5s infinite; }
...
```

And could then be appended to to document's `head` like so:

```
$('head').append('<style type="text/css">/*css rules here*/</style>');
```

[Proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/hxADc/1/) (with rather horrible styles being added 5 seconds into the page load)

**NB:** I've noticed that with GPU acceleration enabled, the FPS counter gets triggered on my Chrome. That leads me to speculate this is *may be* in fact a  better performing approach, compared to jQuery animation.

## Update:

Seing Katti's comment re intending to *change the style values every few seconds* - I'd rather you not. You could very well get away with generating only a fixed subset of animations; imo the [Cicada Principle](http://designfestival.com/the-cicada-principle-and-why-it-matters-to-web-designers/) would be highly applicable in this scenario - just think of movement rather than graphical patterns when reading the article. A truly random animation would not look realistic unless applied to an extremely large amount of small particles (which would likely kill the browser) - meaning that animating pre-rendered sprites would be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I hope you read my comment. With this I would be appending tons of styles. As I would like to change the style values every few seconds.

Comment: @Katti: I've updated my answer to elaborate on why recycling a subset of animation patterns would be the most appropriate solution - especially if you're going for the effect only (as opposed to a simulation of a smoke particle system)

Comment: Thanks that link was greatly helpful.

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing u need to animate some elements using javascript.. as in increasing the `height`|`width`.. this should be a good place to start..

[**Tutorial**](http://javascript.info/tutorial/animation)

Comment: Yeah animation only. But for a reason I wanna do it using keyframes only. Though solution is available with jQuery animate.

Comment: Please use proper English (not "u" instead of "you" etc.) in your answer and do not just link to an external resource.