# webkit animation not working, # before @ in css

Tags: css

The site where I want my animation to work adds #user-space before any of my  tags. So, my animation looks like this:

```
   #user-space @-webkit-keyframes animation-name {
 from {
   style definition ["Before"-state]
 }
 to {
   style definition ["After"-state]
 }
```

And that #user-space declaration is breaking the css statement and animation is not working. Is there any way, to do that otherwise? For exaple put my keyframes insine      -`webkit-animation: animation-name 1.1s ease infinite;` like 
`webkit-animation:  from {
       style definition ["Before"-state]
     }
     to {
       style definition ["After"-state]
     } 1.1s ease infinite;` like

Answer (score 0):

The solution I see is to get around your problem and do it with javascript.

Simply add a new `style` in your html file (in the header) and add the `@-webkit-keyframes` animation inside.

There is a thread which explains it well (see accepted solution): [Set the webkit-keyframes from/to parameter with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328933/set-the-webkit-keyframes-from-to-parameter-with-javascript)