# How to write CSS3 animations with JavaScript objects?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

For the animation library I'm making, I want transitions and animations.

Transitions were simple. I can easily access the transition property from the style property of an element object:

```
   document.body.style['-webkit-transition'] = "background 1s";
   document.body.background = "#f00";
```

I know that in CSS, there are 2 parts to animations, @-keyframes and then calling the actual animation.

How do I **assign** an @-keyframe rule through pure JavaScript?

It **wouldn't** be something like transitions, because @-keyframe rules aren't applied directly to elements.

An alternative to this would be to dynamically create an @-keyframes rule through JavaScript from a string, and append it to a temporary stylesheet. Kind of sloppy, which is why I'm wondering how to do it directly through the DOM.

Is there a way? From what I have seen on some other sites, you can play animations and stop them at certain keyframes, but how do you **create** the animations themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the CSSOM, which allows you (among the other things) to manipulate the stylesheets loaded in a document. First of all, you need a stylesheet loaded in your document, where you'll add the `@keyframe` rules. If you haven't one, you can dynamically create a `style` HTML element and append it to the `head`. Then you have to obtain the instance of the `CSSStyleSheet` interface that represent the stylesheet, you can either retrieve the `sheet` property of the `style` (or `link`) HTML element, or take it from the list available at `document.styleSheets`.

Once you have the object you can simply call the method `insertRule` on it, passing the whole rule as a string and for second parameter a number indicating the position (before which rule will be added this one).

If you have to manipulate further the animations, give a look at the APIs: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#dom-interfaces http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html

Comment: Do you know any down-to-earth tutorials on using CSSOM in JavaScript? Like a blog post or tutorial site?

Comment: I searched a bit, but I didn't found much, this article is the best I found: http://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/. It makes examples exactly with animation rules.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen any javascript api solution but it is possible with css styles generated from javaScript.

Check out http://krazyjakee.github.io/jQuery.Keyframes/ if you using jQuery.

If you whant pure javascript solition then take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328933/set-the-webkit-keyframes-from-to-parameter-with-javascript)

Comment: Yes. This involves appending the animation as a string into a style tag. Not what I wanted, but I can do that.